# visual studio code javascript destructuring assignment create new line on format

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I had some issues with destructuring assignment shorthand when auto formatting JavaScript and TypeScript code in Visual Studio Code.
I got result like this:

```
var {
    check,
    validationResult
} = require("express-validator/check");
```

but I need it to looks like this:

```
var { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator/check");
```

I have **Beautify** installed, and in my settings:

```
{
    "editor.wordWrapColumn": 160,
    "typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": false,
    "typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": false,
    "javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": false,
    "javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": false
}
```

I don't find anywhere else I could set place new line to false.
Any idea how to set it right?

Comment: Did you every figure this one out?  I'm still wrestling with this in a non-React environment.

Comment: @raychz Actually no. But the format works as expected if I use `import {...} from 'module'` I also removed `Beautify`, and keep `Prettier` only

Comment: I had the same problem. Fixed it by uninstalling Beautify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice this problem may resolve by changing the file extension when React component involved.
For example:

*.js -> *.jsx
*.ts -> *.tsx

Visual Studio Code seems to have trouble to format JSX when it's in the wrong type of file.

ESLint and "JavaScript and TypeScript intelliSense" extensions seems also don't like it.

Webpack works no matter what.